# Eclipse RCP application crashes when using scroll in a SWT file browser

Tags: eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, jvm-crash, rhel7

My Eclipse(version 3.7.2 32 bit) RCP application crashes on an RHEL 7 machine every time I open file browser and scroll through the folders list to select a folder--by scroll I mean: clicking on the navigation scroll bar on the right side of the file browser, or even typing the name of a folder which will automatically scroll the view to the folder beginning with the letter/s I type. But this doesn't happen if I don't scroll while the file browser is open and just select a folder/file that's already in the view of the browser and this doesn't happen if I scroll anywhere else in my application.
Also, this only happens on RHEL 7 (not RHEL 6 or 5, or an AIX, or SUSE Linux) when I am using Exceed, Xming to export the display to a Windows machine. 
After the crash there is a JVM core dump with this error(please note I see the first 2 warnings below as soon as my GUI launches in Windows, but the crash happens and the exception stack appears on the RHEL console only when I scroll in the file browser):

```
(configmgr:7277): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",

(configmgr:7277): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
Unhandled exception
Type=Segmentation error vmState=0x00040000
J9Generic_Signal_Number=00000004 Signal_Number=0000000b Error_Value=00000000 Signal_Code=00000080
Handler1=F7153CF5 Handler2=F71280EE InaccessibleAddress=00000000
EDI=D5022550 ESI=0ACBC800 EAX=0ACBC848 EBX=D525F000
ECX=00000003 EDX=0B789B58
EIP=D5022335 ES=002B DS=002B ESP=FFD39AC4
EFlags=00010246 CS=0023 SS=002B EBP=09E29D00
Module=/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
Module_base_address=D4DAF000
Target=2_40_20141010_216764 (Linux 3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64)
CPU=x86 (2 logical CPUs) (0x16ad4d000 RAM)
----------- Stack Backtrace -----------
(0xF711B13A [libj9prt24.so+0xc13a])
(0xF71276AF [libj9prt24.so+0x186af])
(0xF711B1CD [libj9prt24.so+0xc1cd])
(0xF711B2F0 [libj9prt24.so+0xc2f0])
(0xF711AF6C [libj9prt24.so+0xbf6c])
(0xF71276AF [libj9prt24.so+0x186af])
(0xF711AFE0 [libj9prt24.so+0xbfe0])
(0xF7154AC1 [libj9vm24.so+0xfac1])
(0xF7154741 [libj9vm24.so+0xf741])
(0xF71276AF [libj9prt24.so+0x186af])
(0xF7153F26 [libj9vm24.so+0xef26])
(0xF7153D79 [libj9vm24.so+0xed79])
(0xF7128266 [libj9prt24.so+0x19266])
(0xF7764410)
---------------------------------------
JVMDUMP039I Processing dump event "gpf", detail "" at 2015/07/20 04:04:40 - please wait.
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested System dump using '/opt/IBM/ECMClient/configure/core.20150720.040440.7277.0001.dmp' in response to an event
JVMPORT030W /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern setting "|/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp %s %c %p %u %g %t e" specifies that the core dump is to be piped to an external program.  Attempting to rename either core or core.7356.

JVMDUMP010I System dump written to /opt/IBM/ECMClient/configure/core.20150720.040440.7277.0001.dmp
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Java dump using '/opt/IBM/ECMClient/configure/javacore.20150720.040440.7277.0002.txt' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I Java dump written to /opt/IBM/ECMClient/configure/javacore.20150720.040440.7277.0002.txt
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Snap dump using '/opt/IBM/ECMClient/configure/Snap.20150720.040440.7277.0003.trc' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I Snap dump written to /opt/IBM/ECMClient/configure/Snap.20150720.040440.7277.0003.trc
JVMDUMP013I Processed dump event "gpf", detail "".
```

I see that the module Module=/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 is flagged above, but am not sure what's causing this. Also, if it helps, I don't see this module in the /lib path in my RHEL 6 and 5. Can I try installing a different GTK module for RHEL 7 and try, or what else can I do? 
TIA

Comment: Eclipse 3.7.2 is very old, any fixes for this problem would be in newer versions of Eclipse (4.5 being the current release).

Comment: Thank you, but am looking at why this error is happening in general on RHEL 7 and specifically in that module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to problem with IBM JRE. There has been a bug raised on it and it has been fixed in the latest build of Java 8. [APAR IV78992](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV78992)

Please refer to [Bug 457656](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=457656)